# How to render map from postgis data in a java dynamic project (using eclipse luna)?

Tags: java, eclipse, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I am a newbie in Java. I have created a 'dynamic java project'(java7) using eclipse luna and succesfully rendered a html page. What I want is to create a dynamic map from postgis-postgresql to show & query different layers. For that I installed geoserver but don't know how to configure.

Comment: Which Openlayers version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer comes with copious documentation, I would start with the [Getting Started section](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/index.html) which walks you through adding a shapefile and a postgis table.

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) also provides some [great documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/doc/quickstart.html) and many [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/).

Comment: thank you..I got map using geoserver. Can you please suggest me a method to cache the map as images (like png,jpeg,etc). Do I need to install geotools or  cache it using geoserver itself

Comment: use the built in geowebcache http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html